# Confusion in power supply specification of op-amp

Tags: power-supply, voltage, operational-amplifier, amplifier

I don't understand the power supply specification of the op-amp AD826.

The datasheet says:

> Specified for +5 V, ±5 V and ±15 V Operation
>
> [...]
>
> The AD826 can operate from a single +5 V supply, while still achieving 25 MHz of bandwidth. Furthermore the AD826 is fully specified from a single
>   +5 V to ±15 V power supplies.

1. Does it work with a single supply of 8 V or 12 V? 0-8 V
2. Is the reference to "+5 V to ±15 V" referring to the inverting and non-inverting terminal needing to have a voltage difference of 5 V?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your quote does not come from the power supply specification in the datasheet. It comes from the abstract, and it refers to the performance specifications being characterized at the mentioned supply voltages.

1. Did you read [the datasheet](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD826.pdf) all the way through? On pp 4 It clearly states the answer to your questions.
   [image]
2. No. That specification is mentioned elsewhere. See the other two excellent answers for more info on that

Answer (score 2):

Power supply operating range: -

[image]

Absolute maximum voltage between inverting and non-inverting inputs: -

[image]

Operationally it might not recommend more than +/- 5 volts

> 2- is this line "+5 V to ±15 V" says inv and non-inv terminal should
>   have a voltage difference of 5v?

In the data sheet I looked at I couldn't find the line above. For instance, the word "difference" is only used once but not in this context at all.

Comment: lol SNAP.......

Comment: @Trevor_G hehehe

Comment: Great minds think alike, yeah?

Comment: @MrGerber or maybe stupid minds think alike (in a limited way of course).

Comment: LOL I love the cut of your jib @Andyaka. Me thinks we are more alike than ever..

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the actual data sheet not the marketing blurb.

[image]

From that you can see you can drive it with anything up to 36V between the power pins. You can drive it with 0 and +8V if you wish. What performance you get will be somewhere between the numbers specified at 5V and +-5V (i.e. 10V).

The differential input voltage is the maximum difference between the + and - pins.